# How to test eclipse context menu actions?

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, eclipse-gef

From a Junit plugin test I want to test "Delete from Model", which have its associated DeleteFromModelAction. As the action cannot be instantiated normally, I try to mock it. I have came up with the following code.
But it never actually calls the underlying code( dmo.removeZentaElementFromModel()) , which would actually delete the diagram model object (I see it from the log).

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Test
public void It_is_possible_to_delete_from_model_through_a_diagram_object() {
    IZentaElement element = testdata.createClassedTestElement();
    IZentaDiagramModel dia = testdata.getNonTemplateDiagramModel();
    IDiagramModelZentaObject dmo = ModelAndEditPartTestData.createDMOFor(element);
    dia.getChildren().add(dmo);
    testdata.focusOnDiagram(dia.getId());
    BasicObjectEditPart editPart = (BasicObjectEditPart) testdata.getEditPartFor(dmo.getId());
    assertNotNull(editPart);
    editPart.getViewer().appendSelection(editPart);
    DeleteFromModelAction action = mock(DeleteFromModelAction.class);
    ISelection selection = editPart.getViewer().getSelection();
    EcorePlugin.INSTANCE.log(String.format("selection=%s\n",selection));

    assertNotNull(dmo.eContainer());
    action.run();
    EcorePlugin.INSTANCE.log(String.format("removing(1) %s\n",dmo));
    //dmo.removeZentaElementFromModel();
    assertNull(dmo.eContainer());
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually use your "mock" object `action`?

Comment: Maybe I am absolutely confused. I am trying to get an instance of an object which does not have a constructor.

Comment: The way to get the action is through the action registry, which can be obtained by a getAdapter.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actions for the editor can be obtained with a getAdapter() call.
One should use those exact actions because they will get the selection updates.

```
public void It_is_possible_to_delete_from_model_through_a_diagram_object() {
    //setup model
    IZentaElement element = testdata.createClassedTestElement();
    IZentaDiagramModel dia = testdata.getNonTemplateDiagramModel();
    IDiagramModelZentaObject dmo = ModelAndEditPartTestData.createDMOFor(element);
    dia.getChildren().add(dmo);
    testdata.focusOnDiagram(dia.getId());

    //here we obtain the editpart which will be deleted
    BasicObjectEditPart editPart = (BasicObjectEditPart) testdata.getEditPartFor(dmo.getId());
    EditPartViewer viewer = editPart.getViewer();
    //set the selection on the viewer
    viewer.appendSelection(editPart);

    //obtain the editor, its action registry, and our action from it
    ZentaDiagramEditor editor = testdata.getEditor();
    ActionRegistry actionregistry = (ActionRegistry) editor.getAdapter(ActionRegistry.class);
    IAction action = actionregistry.getAction(DeleteFromModelAction.ID);

    //run the action
    assertNotNull(dmo.eContainer());
    action.run();
    assertNull(dmo.eContainer());
}
```